# For limits, does the $\varepsilon$ limit the $\delta$, or does the $\delta$ limit the $\varepsilon$?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

For  $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$, the way I've always thought that $f(x)$ can get "close" to $L$ if $x$ is "close enough" to $a$. So I've worked with the $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ first and then match it with the $0<|x-a|<\delta$. This way, for any $\epsilon$ I can show there exists a $\delta$.

But, at least on YouTube, some people go in the opposite way and I'm wondering if there is a reason for this. They seem to conceptualize it like this: if $x$ is close to $a$ then  $f(x)$ can get close to $L$"

Which is the correct (or better) way of thinking about it? Also, what are the issues if thought about in the incorrect (or worse) way?

Comment: $\delta$ is typically dependent on $\epsilon$.

Comment: The [$\epsilon$-$\delta$ def](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Example_1) says that "for every $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that...". This means that we have to find a way to "manufacture" a suitable $\delta$ from an $\epsilon$ whatever.

Comment: But when we have found $\delta$, the proof must go this way : assuming that $|x-a| < \delta$, check that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Comment: A better way to say the first is $f(x)$ must be close to $L$ if $x$ is close enough to $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking up Mauro ALLEGRANZA's  comments, the order of quantifiers is important.  The definition requires that for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta \ldots$, so you start with an $\epsilon$ and find a $\delta$ that supports that $\epsilon$.  The $\delta$ (almost) always depends on $\epsilon$.  To prove the limit is as you say, you then start with $|x-a| \lt \delta(\epsilon)$ and prove $|f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon$.

If you go the other way, you don't know how close you have to get.  I can certainly choose a $\delta$, compute $\epsilon$ and prove that $|x-a| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon$ but we don't know if that is close enough.  Let $f(x)=10^{-9}$ and somebody claim that $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)=0$  If they start with $\delta=1$ they can prove that $|f(x)-L| \lt 10^{-8}$.  It sounds impressive, but they fail if we choose $\epsilon $ smaller than $10^{-9}$.  That is why the correct definition starts with "For any $\epsilon \gt 0$"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difference in essence.

Saying *$f(x)$ can get close to $L$ if $x$ is close enough to $a$* or *if $x$ is close (enough) to $a$ then $f(x)$ can get close to $L$* is a matter of linguistic style, and not mathematical difference.